# How do I create a unique identifier in a SharePoint list, to give each item a number?

Tags: custom-list, unique

I want each item in a list to have a unique number. I know I have done this in a previous job.

I have created a list and I can't determine which SITE COLUMN to add -- or how to CREATE my own column to accomplish this.

I am using a version of SharePoint that is a hybrid of 2010 and 2013.

Thank you!

Comment: Each list and library has a built in unique id column, called ID.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Out of the box ID column inorder to have unique ID for your list item.

Go to List Tab > Modify view > Check the ID column and click Ok.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I knew it was something simple, but I was looking in the List Settings instead of Modify View.